# Unbounded initial data: Which solution space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Suppose we are given an initial value problem
$$
u_t=u_{xx} +f(u), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}, t>0,
$$
with an initial datum $u(x,0)$ which is **unbounded**.

Does it then make sense to search for (essentially) bounded solutions $u$, when the initial datum already is unbounded, i.e. would that be a well-defined problem?

I guess not. But what could be an appropriate solution space? Maybe some weighted function space that renders the initial datum and the corresponding solution (essentially) bounded?

I am aware that the answer probably depends on the concrete choice of $f$ and on the unbounded initial datum. But maybe, my question can be answered in general, nonetheless.

Comment: Do you mean essentially bounded in time and space? Or essentially bounded in space for every fixed time $t>0$?

Comment: I think I mean essentially bounded in space for each $t>0$ fixed.

Comment: At least if $f=0$ and the initial datum is integrable, then this problem is well-posed because of the strong smoothing properties of the heat kernel (this phenomenon is called *ultracontractivity*). So I would expect the answer to still be positive if the nonlinearity $f$ is small in a suitable sense.

Comment: In the other direction, If I remember correctly, there is work by Fujita that shows that the problem is not even well-posed for bounded boundary data if $f$ grows to fast.